# Magento 2: How add only label field in Ui form?

Tags: magento2, adminform, ui-form

I have text field in Ui form

```
<field name="view">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">View</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">view</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

It's shows like this but I want only label instead of textbox

[image]

Comment: `<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">label</item>` ?

Comment: @AnkitShah I already tried this but it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

Can't find answer for this anywhere, so will leave my solution on this old thread:

```
<field formElement="input" name="field_name">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Field label</label>
        <dataScope>field name</dataScope>
        <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/text</elementTmpl>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Comment: This approach is actually simple and elegant. Works as expected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Input type "text" with read-only : true and with CSS hide the borders. This is uggly but works